# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I am doing a flask tutorial from youtube. But however i always get this error. I even copied his code and tried on my pc, but it still raise that error.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///test.db"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Task %r>" % self.id


@app.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        task_content = request.form["content"]
        new_task = Todo(content=task_content)
        try:
            db.session.add(new_task)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect("/")
        except:
            return "There was an issue adding your task"
    else: 
        tasks = Todo.query.order_by(Todo.date_created).all()
        return render_template("index.html", tasks=tasks)
        # return "hello"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And this is the error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: todo
>   [SQL: SELECT todo.id AS todo_id, todo.content AS todo_content, todo.date_created AS todo_date_created 
>   FROM todo ORDER BY todo.date_created]

Answer (score 0):

You must create db with tables before trying to call it. Answer in the error text.

Try to read [documentation](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) There is lot of information for you. Check method: [create_all](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy.create_all) and second code example from documentation:

```
>>> from yourapplication import db
>>> db.create_all()
```